# Teamcity VCS Build Trigger not working

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.1

Im using TeamCity 7.1, i have configured my build configuration and added a VCS build trigger for trigger the build when check-in completed.(VCS Trigger configuration is default, i havent changed it)

After i push my code to git, teamcity realizes it(as you can see => http://prntscr.com/17j33d), but not triggering the build.

I want to trigger the build when change detected on source.

Comment: I have pretty much the exact same problem, with Subversion and TeamCity 8.0.2.  This was working in a different build configuration for the same project.

Comment: currently it is working altough i havent change anything :)

Comment: I got mine working by the expedient of recreating the entire build configuration from scratch.  I found that if I had no VCS trigger rules defined it works.  As soon as I add one I have to include the "+:." rule (as described in the dialog) even if I delete all the rules.  I suspect that the automatic addition of the "include all" rule is persisted in the XML behind-the-scenes even when you delete all the rules in the dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the "Trigger a build on each check-in" option is checked in the VCS Trigger dialog. I think by default, it is unchecked, so if you are in fact using the default configuration, this might not be enabled.

If that doesn't work, try defining "+:." in the VCS trigger rules, as described by JMD. You can also try deleting the build trigger and creating a new one with the rules you want.